# What is the probability of $\lambda = \mu$ ie. $P(\lambda = \mu)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have given two PDFs as following:
$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    3\lambda x^2 \exp(-\lambda x^3),& \text{if } x> 0\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$g(y)= 
\begin{cases}
    3\mu y^2 \exp(-\mu y^3),& \text{if } y> 0\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Both of these PDFs are independent. What is the probability of $\lambda = \mu$ ie. $P(\lambda = \mu)$?

**My attempt:**
I have already shown that
$$P(X<Y) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$$

**Proof:**
$$P(X<Y) = 1 - P(Y<X)$$
$$P(X<Y) = 1-\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^xf_{XY}(x,y)dy.dx$$
$$P(X<Y) = 1-\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^xf_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)dy.dx$$
$$P(X<Y) = 1-\int_0^{\infty}f_{X}(x)\int_0^x3\mu y^2 \exp(-\mu y^3)dy.dx$$
$$P(X<Y) = 1+\int_0^{\infty}f_{X}(x)(\exp(-\mu x^3) - 1).dx$$
$$P(X<Y) = 1+\int_0^{\infty}3\lambda x^2 \exp(-\lambda x^3)(\exp(-\mu x^3) - 1).dx$$
$$P(X<Y) = 1-\int_0^{\infty}-3\lambda x^2 \exp(-(\lambda+\mu) x^3)dx + \int_0^{\infty}-3\lambda x^2 \exp(-\lambda x^3).dx$$
$$P(X<Y) = 1+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu} - 1$$
$$P(X<Y) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$$

Comment: Probability of what?

Comment: $P(\lambda = \mu)$. There was a typo in the question. I fixed it.

Comment: This is actually a question from the Probability textbook by Rohatgi and Saleh.

Comment: How did you show it?

Comment: @Alex I have added the steps in the main question.

Comment: Well, you have used $P(X<Y)=1-P(Y<X)$. Clearly, $X<Y$, $X=Y$ and $X>Y$ are three alternatives that exclude each other and cover all possibilities. Their probabilities therefore must add up to $1$. What follows for $P(X=Y)$?

Comment: I don't find this question meaningful. $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are deterministic constants. It is only meaningful to talk about probability about $X$ and $Y$ where $X \sim f$ and $Y \sim g$. For example, things like $P(X = Y)$, $P(2X < Y)$, $P(X > Y)$, etc. And by the way, $P(X = Y) = 0$ because $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables.

Comment: @ironX that was my concern as well. But the book gave the value of probability 0.5.

Comment: Sometimes books are wrong, but much more often, the reader (i.e. the poster to MSE) misunderstood the books or forgot to quote the whole section / all relevant details.  Please go back to the book and see if you missed anything.

Comment: @antkam See this is the original question [https://ibb.co/VpKV4SY ]. I have uploaded the snip of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the original question from [here](https://ibb.co/VpKV4SY). You indeed misread it. Here's what it is asking:

The first part is asking for $P(Y > X)$ which can be calculated as:
\begin{align*}
P(Y > X) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_x^\infty \left( 3 \lambda x^2 \exp(-\lambda x^3) \right) \left( 3 \mu y^2 \exp(-\mu y^3) \right) dy \,dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty 3 \lambda x^2 \exp(-\lambda x^3) \left [\, \int_x^\infty 3 \mu \exp(-\mu y^3) dy \, \right ] dx \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}  
\end{align*}

The second part is asking to evaluate the answer when $\lambda = \mu$ which is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Intuitively, $\lambda = \mu$ implies symmetry so $P(X > Y) = P(Y > X) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Notes:

1. $P(X = Y) = 0$
2. The question never asked for $P(\lambda = \mu)$. Still, in some contexts, one may write: $$P(\lambda = \mu) = \begin{cases}
   1 & \lambda = \mu\\
   0 & \lambda \neq \mu
   \end{cases}$$

Comment: What does $P(\lambda=\mu)$ even mean?